# A property average.

Tags: analysis

Let $\Omega \supset B_4$ and $f \in L^1(\Omega)$. Let $x_0 \in B_1$ such that there exists a $\delta >0 $ where 
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{1}{|B_r(x_0)|} \int_{B_r(x_0)} |f|^2dx \le \delta
\end{equation}
for all $B_r(x_0) \subset \Omega$ and for some contante $\delta$. Show that
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{1}{|B_4|} \int_{B_4} |f|^2dx \le 2^n \delta.
\end{equation}

Comment: I strongly suspect this is not true. Take $\Omega = B_4$. Suppose $x_0 = e_n$. Then you can set $f = 0$ on $B_3(x_0)$, satisfying the first condition with $\delta = 0$, but set $f$ to be arbitrarily large on $B_4 \setminus B_3(x_0)$, making the second integral arbitrarily large.

Comment: Ray Yang, you are right. I forgot to say $\delta >0$. Where I've saw is not written but I think that we need that $B_5 \subset \Omega$ or $B_8 \subset$, because this way we obtain
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{1}{|B_4|}|f|^2dx \le \dfrac{1}{|B_8|}\int_{B_8}|f|^2dx \le 2^n\dfrac{1}{|B_8|} \int_{B_8}|f|^2 dx \le 2^n\delta
\end{equation}

Comment: What you need is some sort of regularity condition on $f$. Is there one? I think if $f$ is just in some $L^p$ space, you can never make this work, as GilYoung's answer below explains.

Comment: Yes, you can suppose that $f\in L^p$.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this answer would satisfy you, but I think that this is not necessarily true (and I'm pretty sure this is similar to what Ray Yang discerned). I will use notation $m(B)$ instead of $|B|$ for Lebesgue measure.

Let $\Omega = B_{4}$. Since $m(B_{r}(x_{0})) = m(B_{r}(0)) = c_{n}r^{n}$ for some $c_{n} > 0$, the first condition only gives you $\int_{B_{r}(x_{0})}|f|^{2}dx \leq \delta c_{n}r^{n}$ if $B_{r}(x_{0})$. That is, you can only bound your integral in a portion of $\Omega$ (especially if $x_{0}$ is near the boundary of $B_{4}$).

The problem asks you whether you can bound $\int_{B_{4}}|f|^{2}dx$. What you are given does not tell us anything about this integral on $B_{4} \setminus B_{R}(x_{0})$ ($R = \sup\{R > 0 : B_{R}(x_{0}) \subseteq B_{4}\}$) unless $x_{0} = 0$. That is, the integral may be very large in this region.